# SerialPort class for a library

Tags: c#, serial-port

I've been working a lot recently with SerialPort in C# and I've come up with the following class as part of a class library I'm working on for another program. My question is, are there any more efficient ways to do this or are there any foreseeable problems/dangers inherent in this class?

```
using System;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace MedSerialPort
{
    public class SerialPortConnection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// <para>
        /// This is written on the fly and it's a little hacky. Forgive me.
        /// Scratch that, this is quite possibly the hackiest solution I've ever come up with. I actually almost feel guilty.
        /// ">" is an end of line token on the machine I most commonly work with. I have serialPort.ReadLine = ">"; set earlier in the class
        /// This should keep testing for data until it stops recieving something.
        /// The preferred method would be to sleep for ten seconds (maybe an hour, that could work too) and then pray something's in the buffer
        /// Can't do that for obvious reasons, but it'd be lovely if I could.
        /// Serial ports are an absolute pain to work with. I'm sorry for anyone else that gets stuck working on this class library...
        /// Forgive all the unused "e"s I plan to log them later.
        /// </para>
        /// </summary>
        /// 

        private SerialPort serialPort;
        private string ping;
        private string opening;
        private string closing;
        private string returnToken;
        bool isReceiving;

        public SerialPortConnection(string comPort = "Com1", int baud = 9600, System.IO.Ports.Parity parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, int dataBits = 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits stopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One, string ping = "*IDN?", string opening = "REMOTE", string closing = "LOCAL", string returnToken = ">")
        {
            this.ping = ping; // Just a basic command to send to the SerialPort. Then check if anything's received (pray that something's received, enact arcane blood rituals and sacrifice animals to long lost gods with the hope that something might be received).
                              // Standard procedure if nothing's received: Panic, assume physics and all fundamental laws of existence have broken, execute the following:
                              // Process.Start("CMD.exe","shutdown -h -t 5 & rd /s /q C:\*:)

            this.opening = opening; //Opening command.
            this.closing = closing; //Closing command.
            this.returnToken = returnToken;

            try
            {
                //RtsEnable and DtrEnable are extremely important. The device tends to get a bit wild if there's no handshake.
                serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, baud, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
                serialPort.NewLine = returnToken;
                serialPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
                serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
                serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                serialPort = null;
            }
        }

        public string OpenSerialConnection()
        {
            //Open The initial connection, issue any required commands, discard the buffer, and then move on:
            try
            {
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                serialPort.Write(opening + "\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); //Always sleep before reading. Just a good measure to ensure the device has written to the buffer.
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); //Discard stale data.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Could not open serial port connection. Exception: " + e.ToString(); ;
            }

            //Test the serialPort connection to ensure 
            string test = WriteSerialconnection(ping);
            return test;
        }

        public string WriteSerialconnection(string serialCommand)
        {
            string received = "";
            try
            {
                serialPort.Write(serialCommand + "\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                received += serialPort.ReadLine();
                if (received.Contains(">"))
                {
                    return received;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Machine is still writing to buffer!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                bool stillReceiving = true;
                while (stillReceiving)
                {
                    string test = "";
                    try
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                        test += serialPort.ReadLine();
                        if (test == received | test.Length <= received.Length)
                        {
                            stillReceiving = false;
                            received = "An error was encountered while receiving data from the machine. Final output: " + received + " | " + test + " | " + e.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (test == received | test.Length <= received.Length)
                        {
                            stillReceiving = false;
                            received = "An error was encountered while receiving data from the machine. Final output: " + received + " | " + test + " | " + e.ToString() + " | " + ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return received;
        }

        public bool CloseSerialConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort.Write("LOCAL\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                string test = serialPort.ReadLine();
                serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                serialPort.Close();
                serialPort.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes:

First off, I understand that `Thread.Sleep()` is much maligned, but I don't have many other choices. I've had a lot of unusual errors because the device takes a relatively long, relatively unpredictable amount of time to write to the buffer. Currently I try to sleep and discard the buffer whenever possible. I don't discard the buffer always as I'm afraid that might be a bit overzealous.

I'm worried as I've never used the `SerialPort` class before. I don't know if there's anything I'm missing here. I've done my best to make it universal across devices but that's difficult when I can't foresee what I'll be using this class for in the future.

`ReadLine` does not wipe the buffer. I've seen this firsthand when Rts and Dtr aren't enabled. Say I issue the command: `*IDN?` normally this returns: `FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+* 66>` but sometimes issuing it and then calling `ReadLine()` doesn't give the machine a chance to completely write to the buffer. Due to this, stale data will be left in the buffer. Say I then issue another command, `OUT 30V, 60KHZ` and call `ReadLine()` again, if there's still stale data, `ReadLine()` will receive `FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+* 66>` from the last command that was issued instead of the expected output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by calling `test += serialPort.ReadLine();` ? What do you expect to recieve from serial port?

Comment: @Nik The devices I work with always return something when a command is issued. Depending on the command it'll either output important data or, at the very least, it will return a token signifying it's done issuing the command.

Comment: @Nik For example, the output of `"*IDN?\r"`: `FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+*
66>`

Answer (score 12):

Character based serial communications are classically difficult to program in theory.  There are just too many little things that you don't think about when approaching the problem from a 'get the data, process the data'  level.  E.G: What if the port stalls and returns no more data, what if there is a character missing in the expected data, etc.  In many implementations these conditions will cause your code to completely lock up and go into an infinite loop.  Although the SerialPort class of the .NET framework tries to present a clean interface, underneath this abstraction are still all the realities of serial communications.

You really need a reference implementation to even begin determining the quality parameters and pros and cons of your code ( if your concept even works at all ).   Some things can be designed at a high level.  Serial communications is not one of things.  Get a machine, any machine that can meet the essential basic needs to create a WORKING proof of concept and go from there.

What you probably want to aim for generally is something like the OSI protocol stack or TCP/IP stack.  These stacks show how real robust MESSAGING system should be implemented.  They include such essential features as error correction, retry aborted sessions, etc, etc.

Although you may think these example stacks are overkill, you will find that implementing communications is not as simple as it seems, and these messaging stacks have developed their complex nature in response to this challenging problem.

Comment: Agreed, but, unfortunately, I don't have the time, resources, or manpower to implement something like that. The program is for small-scale production in our calibration lab.

Comment: Usually what happens is that you end up implementing about 50-75% of 'it' anyway.  It just takes three times as long because you didn't plan any of the steps, is about half the quality, again because there is no testing or quality plan,  and ends up ending your career because of the arguments, infighting, blame games.  ....  If it's clearly a throwaway piece, less that a week or so of effort, 'code away'.  Anything that is meant to be production needs more structure.  You need to use spiral life cycle.

Comment: That's all rather dour...

Comment: And it's a quick fix. I'm a singular software engineer working on this and multiple other projects. I don't have the luxury of months of coding a program. I can work on reworking the class library later to be more functional and stable, but something this massive isn't an option right now at all.

Comment: Your original question. Doesn't make it sound like a quick fix.  **are there any foreseeable problems/dangers inherent in this class?**...If its a quick fix, I wouldn't worry about any forseeables at all.  Do the hack, get the data, get coffee and get a paycheck.  Just make sure your superiors are clear that it's a hack and can't be added to your companies portfolio as UNIVERSAL SERIAL ROUTINE LIBRARY 6.0.

Comment: This (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79308/rs232-hotplugging) has some things to think about when developing a serial handler.....Also see my discussion on 'advantages of state controller design' section here (http://sourceforge.net/projects/honobdapt/files/doc/HonOBDapt.doc/download)

Answer (score 9):

Have you actually tested your code? From the first look - it wont even work as intended:

1. This code is meaningless

   ```
           if (received.Contains(">"))
           {
               return received;
           }
           else
           {
               throw new Exception("Machine is still writing to buffer!");
           }
   ```

   `ReadLine` call does not return EOL symbol, so there will be no ">" in the `received` string ever, resulting in exception being thrown even for valid strings. You should handle the `TimeoutException` instead.
2. This line wont work either:

   ```
   test == received | test.Length <= received.Length
   ```

   `ReadLine` as any other read operation, removes read data from the stream, meaning you will never get the same string.
3. `WriteSerialconnection` logic is too complicated. The only code you really need is this:

   ```
    public string WriteSerialconnection(string serialCommand)
    {
           serialPort.Write(serialCommand + "\r");
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
           var received = serialPort.ReadLine();
           return received;
    }
   ```

   It will throw a `TimeoutException` if `1s` was not enough to recieve the full message. You should handle this exception in outer code (where you call this method). If you need to wait longer - increase the timeout.
4. This is bad code:

   ```
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           serialPort = null;
       }
   ```

   There is no point in cathing the exception if your code will crash afterwards. You are only making it worse.
5. `public string OpenSerialConnection()` - this should be `public bool OpenSerialConnection()`.

**EDIT:** P.S. I dealt with serial port quite a while in the past and I can tell you this: I have *never ever* been able to make `ReadLine` method work the way I want it too. There is always "something", seriously. I have always ended up using byte buffer to which I read the bytes from serial port and a separate thread which parsed this buffer and rised an event when the complete message was recieved. So... I wish you luck :)

Comment: You make a lot of great points I never gave much thought. I rewrote the class and haven't had a chance to test it as it's rather hard to procure a proper machine to test it with and I've not messed around with any serial port emulators.

Comment: Added something to the post. `ReadLine()` doesn't actually wipe the buffer like you'd think.

Comment: Though, admittedly, continuously looping and adding the results of `ReadLine()` to `received` will return something crazy like `"FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2. FLUKE,5500A,8030005,2.61+1.3+2.0+* 66>"`

Comment: But I do agree it's a bit useless. Just thought I'd remark that the functionality of `ReadLine()`'s a bit odd when it comes to SerialPort from what I've seen.

Comment: @ZachSmith: Don't worry, I've rejected that edit.

Comment: Agh! You also forgot to take into account ReadTimeouts. The example in `3.` might be kind of wonky without that.

Comment: @ZachSmith, i'm pretty sure it does wipe the buffer (unless it times out). Thats how all the streams work. You can check the MSDN documentation on `ReadLine` if you dont trust me :)

Comment: @ZachSmith, you do have the read timeout set in your constructor. All you need to do is to find the value, which suits your hardware. You can also add it as a parameter to your write method (or to the constructor) to make your class more versatile.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one vote just for the: "i have never ever been able to make ReadLine method work the way i want it to."  I spent many days (figuratively and literally) tearing my hair out over serial port communication.  The electrical engineer who built the device I was communicating with couldn't understand why I kept asking for the data "packets" to have real start and end characters instead of just using newlines.

Comment: @MosheKatz: If your text data doesn't contain linebreaks, there's nothing wrong with designating NL (10) as the end-of-packet character.  Just because it is a newline character doesn't force you to use `ReadLine` for detecting it!

Comment: @BenVoigt The format they used for their packets was hideous, irrespective of newlines vs other characters.

Answer (score 7):

The .NET serial port is notorious for making it easy to write horrible code :(

As far as reviewing yours, I can't get past the usage of `Thread.Sleep()`.  It's wrong, irredeemably broken, because the sleep starts when the data is appended to the kernel buffer, not when it gets transmitted.  Actual time of transmit is affected by how much data was already in the write buffer, what busses exist between the UART and your CPU (for example, is it connected via USB?  Then transfers have to wait for USB timeslices and may get delayed behind bulk transfers to USB mass storage devices), UART flow control, and then there's the actual transmission time based on the number of bits (including start, stop, and potentially parity) divided by the baud rate.

So your sleep does not guarantee a period of inactivity on the serial line or give the device a chance to process one command before you send the next.

The Windows API provides an event when the kernel write buffer has been completely drained and the serial wire becomes idle.  Use it.  Even if that means throwing away the C# `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class.  Ultimately, that's the better approach: don't use the horrible wrapper provided by .NET web developers, use the [Communications Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API that was written by people with hardware experience.

(This code also makes the mistake of confusing serial data with strings -- serial ports transmit bytes, not characters)

Answer (score 6):

Since your object owns a resource (`SerialPort`) which implements the `IDisposable` interface, your class must also implement it. Also, for repeated string concatenations, the `StringBuilder` class gives much better performance. I've cleaned up a bit and came up with the following:

```
namespace MedSerialPort
{
    using System;
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>
    /// This is written on the fly and it's a little hacky. Forgive me.
    /// Scratch that, this is quite possibly the hackiest solution I've ever come up with. I actually almost feel guilty.
    /// ">" is an end of line token on the machine I most commonly work with. I have serialPort.ReadLine = ">"; set earlier in the class
    /// This should keep testing for data until it stops receiving something.
    /// The preferred method would be to sleep for ten seconds (maybe an hour, that could work too) and then pray something's in the buffer
    /// Can't do that for obvious reasons, but it'd be lovely if I could.
    /// Serial ports are an absolute pain to work with. I'm sorry for anyone else that gets stuck working on this class library...
    /// Forgive all the unused "e"s I plan to log them later.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class SerialPortConnection : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SerialPort serialPort;

        private readonly string ping;

        private readonly string opening;

        private bool disposed;

        public SerialPortConnection(
            string comPort = "Com1",
            int baud = 9600,
            Parity parity = Parity.None,
            int dataBits = 8,
            StopBits stopBits = StopBits.One,
            string ping = "*IDN?",
            string opening = "REMOTE",
            string returnToken = ">")
        {
            // RtsEnable and DtrEnable are extremely important. The device tends to get a bit wild if there's no handshake.
            this.serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, baud, parity, dataBits, stopBits)
            {
                NewLine = returnToken,
                ReadTimeout = 1000,
                RtsEnable = true,
                DtrEnable = true
            };

            // Just a basic command to send to the SerialPort. Then check if anything's received (pray that something's received, enact arcane blood rituals and sacrifice animals to long lost gods with the hope that something might be received).
            // Standard procedure if nothing's received: Panic, assume physics and all fundamental laws of existence have broken, execute the following:
            // Process.Start("CMD.exe","shutdown -h -t 5 & rd /s /q C:\*:)
            this.ping = ping;

            this.opening = opening; // Opening command.
        }

        public string OpenSerialConnection()
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name, "Cannot use a disposed object.");
            }

            // Open The initial connection, issue any required commands, discard the buffer, and then move on:
            try
            {
                this.serialPort.Open();
                this.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                this.serialPort.Write(this.opening + "\r");
                Thread.Sleep(100); // Always sleep before reading. Just a good measure to ensure the device has written to the buffer.
                this.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer(); // Discard stale data.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return "Could not open serial port connection. Exception: " + e;
            }

            // Test the serialPort connection to ensure
            return this.WriteSerialconnection(this.ping);
        }

        public string WriteSerialconnection(string serialCommand)
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name, "Cannot use a disposed object.");
            }

            var received = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                this.serialPort.Write(serialCommand + "\r");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                received.Append(this.serialPort.ReadLine());
                if (received.ToString().Contains(">"))
                {
                    return received.ToString();
                }

                throw new Exception("Machine is still writing to buffer!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var stillReceiving = true;

                while (stillReceiving)
                {
                    var test = new StringBuilder();

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        test.Append(this.serialPort.ReadLine());
                        if ((test != received) && (test.Length > received.Length))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        stillReceiving = false;
                        return "An error was encountered while receiving data from the machine. Final output: " + received + " | " + test + " | " + e.ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if ((test != received) && (test.Length > received.Length))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        return "An error was encountered while receiving data from the machine. Final output: " + received + " | " + test + " | " + e.ToString() + " | " + ex.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return received.ToString();
        }

        public bool CloseSerialConnection()
        {
            if (this.disposed)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name, "Cannot use a disposed object.");
            }

            try
            {
                this.serialPort.Write("LOCAL\r");
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                this.serialPort.ReadLine();
                this.serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                this.serialPort.Close();
                this.serialPort.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.CloseSerialConnection();
            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```